# Enable & disable remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The user of app must to have the possibility to enable / disable remote notifications by pressing a button on/off.

The app register for remote notifications in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". 
When the user click the button to disable the remote notifications the code is

```
// Register for Push Notifications, if running iOS 8
                    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
                    {
                        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
                        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
                        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
                        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
                        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone];
                    }
```

This works. The remote notifications are disabled !

But when the user click again to enable the remote notifications

```
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
                    {
                        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
                        UIUserNotificationSettings * settingsAvailable = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
                        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settingsAvailable];
                        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
                        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

                    }
```

the app does not register for none of the type (alert, badge or sound)

Some advices ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate out two concepts here: first is asking the user for permission to receive push notifications, which is what you are doing.  Once you have that permission, don't turn it off.  It is my understanding that you only get to ask for this permission once, and after that, changes must be made inside the settings app (Settings -> Notifications).

What you likely should be doing is asking to enable push notifications once, while also tracking in the app and wherever your pushes are generated whether the user wants to receive a push or not.  The *permission* level is managed by iOS.  The secondary (on/off) level is managed by you.

Comment: i tried to do that. everytime when the button switch in on or off, i store this option in userDefault and try to let/ or not to receive  the push notification in AppDelegate "didReceivePushNotifications" but i dont know why the remote notifications are still get it by phone

Comment: None of what you are doing makes sense.  When **didReceiveRemoteNotification** is called it's already too late -- a push has already been sent, received, and the user has probably seen it.  As I said, you should be keeping track of the user's preference yourself, and sending (or not sending) a push notification based on that preference.

Comment: probably you are right and should be the best way to do that. thank you .